# How to use an array in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have numbers in array $x. I have a database with a field number. How do I get all rows where the field number is in the array?  Can I avoid printing out the elements of the array in the query and just reference $x?

Comment: How big can `$x` be?

Comment: 430 questions in database